# How to fix not null header info in WordPress

Tags: java, android, wordpress

In my **WordPress** website I want get my site posts into **json** for create **android application** and for this I install this **plugin** into my **wordPress** for get **json**.
**Plugin link :** http://v2.wp-api.org/

I should use **header** of response in my application, and when log my response log show me this message in my `logCat` (android studio console) :

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type
    Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-WP-Total, X-WP-TotalPages
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
    Server: Apache
    Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
    Last-Modified: Wed, 11 Apr 2018 19:07:42 GMT
    Connection: keep-alive
    Date: Wed, 11 Apr 2018 20:01:36 GMT
```

**I write below code into android studio for get data from server :**

```
public void loadCategories() {

    ApiUtils.getApiInterface().getCategories(perPageCount).enqueue(new Callback<List<Category>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Category>> call, Response<List<Category>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.e("ResponseHeaderLog", response.headers()+"");

                    int totalPages = Integer.parseInt(response.headers().get("x-wp-totalpages"));
```

**When write below code show me above header info :**

```
Log.e("ResponseHeaderLog", response.headers()+"");
```

**but when write code show me null :**

```
Integer.parseInt(response.headers().get("x-wp-totalpages"));
```

how can I fix it and not show null in

```
Integer.parseInt(response.headers().get("x-wp-totalpages"));
```

?

I thing this bug is from my server!!!  How can I fix it? please help me. really need your helps. Thanks

Comment: You want help fixing the null in the android code? or your server code?

Comment: Maybe it is case-sensitive. So try putting `X-WP-TotalPages` instead of `x-wp-totalpages`

Comment: @Derek, I check it. but not fixed. can you help me? please:(